# Google maps: how to find all of the markers inside the map by using gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created some markers by using addMarker() of gmaps.js:

```
var lat= new Array();
var lng= new Array();
var title= new Array();
lat[0]=...
lng[0]=...
title[0]=...
...

for(i=0;i<lat.lenth;i++){
  map.addMarker({
    lat: lat[i],
    lng: lng[i],
    title: title[i],    
  });
}
```

Now, I want to only get the markers that inside the current displayed map and display the lists of site to the table. How can I do that? Is there any API from gmaps.js can implement with ease?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the map's bounds, and then see if that bounds contains each marker.

```
var bounds = map.getBounds();

for (var i=0;i<lat.length;i++) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i], lng[i]);

  map.addMarker({
    lat: lat[i],
    lng: lng[i],
    title: title[i],    
  });

  if (bounds.contains(latlng)) {
    // add the details into an array here.  After the loop, output the contents to a div
  }
}
```